# Throwing exception from a function parameter

Tags: c++, c++20

Does the code below produce a memory leak?

```
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>

struct A {};

struct B {
    B() {
        throw std::runtime_error("");
    }
};

template <class T>
class MyPtr {
public:
    MyPtr(T* p) : m_p(p) {}

    MyPtr(MyPtr&& other) : m_p(other.m_p) {
        other.m_p = nullptr;
    }

    ~MyPtr() {
        delete m_p;
    }

private:
    T* m_p;
};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(MyPtr<A> a, MyPtr<B> b) : m_a(std::move(a)), m_b(std::move(b)) {}

private:
    MyPtr<A> m_a;
    MyPtr<B> m_b;
};

int main() {
    try {
        Foo foo(new A(), new B());
    }
    catch (const std::exception&) {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a difference between

```
Foo foo(new A(), new B());
```

and

```
Foo foo(MyPtr(new A()), MyPtr(new B()));
```

?

Comment: You can figure this out for yourself by giving `A` and `B` destructors that print something to `cout`.

Comment: @PaulSanders it is a right way to learn JavaScript but not C++.

Comment: @PaulSanders Not running the dtor (as it happens with `B`) does not necessarily mean memory leak. Here we leak, but not b/c of that.

Comment: @lorro Sure, but that's not what I was getting at, I'm saying it can be used as a diagnostic

Comment: Side note:  Obviously this is a simplified example, but if you didn't leave out the observance of [the Rule of Three and friends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for brevity, please read the link. It'll help you out quite a bit later.

Answer (score 5):

The evaluation order is based on sequenced-before and sequenced-after in modern C++ versions. This means, the following will happen:

- in any non-overlapping order: `new A()`, `new B()` - memory is allocated for `A` and `B` and constructors are run (these cannot be interleaved)
- since `B` has a ctor, this ctor is run (sequenced-after allocation)
- `B`'s ctor `throw`s
- since `B`'s ctor didn't complete, the memory allocated by `new` *for constructing `B`* will be freed, without calling dtor.

Note that the call to `Foo`'s ctor would be sequenced-after the above, so it won't be reached.

Thus, `B` is not leaked. However, function parameters can be sequenced in any non-overlapping way, so `A` might or might not be leaked. This might, in theory, change from run to run.

If you do: `Foo foo(MyPtr(new A()), MyPtr(new B()));`, then you immediately encapsulate the pointers to smart pointers after `new`, so it won't leak.

Also, it's worth mentioning, while the memory for `B` *is* deallocated, any memory that's allocated in `B`'s ctor and not deallocated till `throw` can still potentially leak. In this example there's no such allocation, but in actual codes it might occur. The only memory deallocated is that of the entire object being constructed.

Comment: @273K It does not leak `B`. We don't know if it leaks `A`. (added a paragraph on in)

Comment: @MooingDuck Allocation and construction is not interleaved. It's the function parameter evaluation that's done in an undefined (but not overlapping) manner: either `new A()` first and `new B()` second, or `new B()` first and `new A()` second. In the former case, `A` is leaked. Added a comment to clarify this.

Comment: oh, I failed to notice that A didn't also throw. You're right

Comment: I thought this was the rule, but I was wrong, as determined by a core issue submission I wrote up in my answer.

Comment: @DavisHerring Can you point to the actual part of the standard what makes you think so? I read your other answer, but the link there is about the second case (where we agree we don't leak, as I wrote in the answer), not the first case. It's about `  f(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int),std::unique_ptr<int>(new int));`, when pointers are wrapped immediately.

Comment: @lorro: What [expr.call]/8 says is indeterminately sequenced is "The initialization of a parameter", not the evaluation of any argument.  That means that either both examples might leak (because the argument expressions, at least if they aren't prvalues of the same type as the parameter, or their subexpressions may be arbitrarily ordered) or neither does (because the entire argument evaluation "and" initialization is atomic).  I asked the question about the "safer" form in order to better illustrate the need for the clarification.

Comment: @DavisHerring I'm pretty sure evaluation order of function arguments is unspecified: see first sentence here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order To be clear, this does not contradict [expr.call]/8, which says "The initialization of a parameter, _including every associated value computation and side effect_, is indeterminately sequenced with respect to that of any other parameter."

Comment: @lorro: Order is unspecified, but we're talking about **interleaving** (_i.e._, is `new A()`, `new B()`, then `MyPtr<A>::MyPtr` allowed, which it's not).  The question was which evaluations are included by "every associated", and the answer is the entire expression and "actual" initialization **together**, which is why it's safe with or without the explicit pointer wrapping.

Comment: @DavisHerring There's leaking without interleaving. Note that, in the _first_ version, user does not put it in managed ptr: `Foo foo(new A(), new B());`. If you do `new A()` first, then `new B()`, and the later fails, we leak.

Comment: @lorro: That order can’t happen: `new A` is part of the initialization of `a`, which must complete before `new B` is evaluated if it has already started.

Comment: @DavisHerring Ok, so to be precise, you do `new A`, you assign it to `a`; then you do `new B` and it throws.

Comment: @lorro: Right, and there’s no leak since `MyPtr<A>::~MyPtr` then happens.

Comment: @DavisHerring Negative. `b` is not bound - `B::B()` throws.

Comment: @lorro: So what?  It’s `new A()` that might leak.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++17, no leak occurs in either case, but this interpretation hinges on the definition of **initialization** of a parameter.  Does the initialization of `a` begin by evaluating `new A()`, or does it start after that expression has already been reduced to a pointer value?  [CWG2599](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2599.html) answers this question with the **broader** choice, as makes sense especially for aggregate initialization where the parameter obviously already exists (albeit only partially initialized) before all the *initializer-clause*s have been evaluated at all.

Comment: Yes there is no leaks with MSVC2022, see my code example https://developernote.com/2022/09/throwing-an-exception-from-a-function-parameter-in-cpp/

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky No leaks might also be due to evaluation order - it's implementation-defined

Comment: Not sure about this, CWG2599 is about the second case: `  f(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int),std::unique_ptr<int>(new int));`.

Comment: @lorro `A` created first in my example, see https://developernote.com/2022/09/throwing-an-exception-from-a-function-parameter-in-cpp/

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Standard allows _either_ to be created first. Since `A` can be trivially constructed, it also allows - via the as-if rule - to allocate the memories together. It also allows compiler to always create the object with throwing ctor to run first and schedule the other ctor & allocation after. That doesn't mean it cannot throw on other architectures.

Comment: @Iorro I understand. I mean that at least on my machine with both MSVC2022 and GCC11 `A` created and destroyed correctly with both `Foo foo(new B(), new A())` and `Foo foo(MyPtr(new B()), MyPtr(new A()))` so it is still not clear enough is there a difference between them or not.